# changing parents css when a class is there

Tags: jquery

I have a somewhat unique situation where I'm trying to lock down some buttons, but only if there is a lock icon present. My issue is the icon is within the button so I need to call the parent and I've looked up how to do it, but everything I look at has either a click function or is to complex for what I need to happen

My button looks like this

```
<a href="#">
  <button>
    <i class=" icon-lock"></i><br>
    <p>Books</p>
  </button>
</a>
```

and the icon is the class that will change to the lock.

Any help would be  much appreciated!

Comment: Why wrapping a button with an anchor?

Comment: totally missed that this was tagged with jQuery rather than CSS.

Comment: I have an anchor wrapping the button because I have dynamic php links and multiple buttons. If It was just a submit form this would not be happening, but its a very complicated ui.

Comment: @zazvorniki - you have to set background: none before you set the background-color green (a workaround). I added the fiddle demo in my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".icon-lock").parent("button").css(...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cCZ5u/1/

Comment: This is coming back as undefined for me....and it's the lock I need changed not the cog

Comment: What is coming back as undefined?  jquery selectors never return undefined.

Comment: `$(".icon-lock").parents("button").css(....` should work here not `parent('button')`.

Comment: I typed this into my console (my git pull isn't updating my live dev site anymore, slight bug) and all it's returning is 'undefined'

Comment: @Anilkumar `parents` will search all the way up the DOM.  `parent` gets the direct parent, which this is.  Your answer also uses `parent`...

Comment: sorry my mistake @JamesMontagne

Comment: It's still not working though, I know this seems to be the logical solution and this is what I initially tried, but it's just not working. None of the css is changing and if I enter it in the console then it returns undefined.

Comment: It works  http://jsfiddle.net/cCZ5u/1/  If it won't work for you then there's some other issue.  As I mentioned, jquery will never return undefined.  Even if nothing is found it returns an empty jquery object.  You have something else going on.

Comment: You didn't include jquery and your inline rule only replaces `background-color` and not all the other background stuff that takes precedent.  http://jsfiddle.net/enzYV/3/

Comment: I didn't save the new one sorry, with it enabled it's still not working http://jsfiddle.net/enzYV/4/

Comment: @zazvorniki See the rest of my comment.

Comment: I saw your comment, but this is the only jquery I have going on in my entire website and that doesn't explain why I won't work in the fiddle I was playing with.

Comment: "Your inline rule only replaces background-color and not all the other background stuff that takes precedent." Such as the gradients and the 10 other `background` properties you have in your css.  This has nothing to do with jquery.  Put `background-color: green` directly on your button and it too will be "ignored".  Using `background: green` instead wipes these other properties and works as shown in my fiddle.

Comment: Then how do I fix that? Do I have to add gradients to the css in the jquery? I'm sorry I'm being a pain, but I'm on a really tight deadline here and I really need this to work.

Comment: You still havent' really described what you're trying to change.  If you want to actually change all of those gradients then I would create 2 classes and use `addClass` and `removeClass`.  Changing all those gradient is nuts.

Answer (score 1):

use `parent()`

`$(".icon-cog").parent().css();`

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/c9tD7/)**

```
$(".icon-lock").parent().css("background","none");
$(".icon-lock").parent().css("background-color", "green");
```